Constructing paths in the complex plane
I'm trying to construct a path for a path integral with the path being the straight line from $i$ to $1$.
My intuition was to see that this looks like the line in the $\mathbb{R}^2$, $y=-x+1$ with $x \in [0,1]$ so my first guess was $\gamma (t) = 1-t$ with $t \in [0,1]$ but this is clearly wrong because it has no complex part.
I know the solution is $\gamma (t) = 1-t + it$ but I'm quite stuck on how to get there.

what are you stuck on? If you know $\gamma(0) = 1$ and $\gamma(1) = i$, are you stuck on proving it is a straight line?

@tbrugere I'm stuck on how to arrive at the solution of $\gamma (t)=1-t+it$ as I said in the question. I know the solution because it was given to me but I don't know how to get there.

well, you know what $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$ should be right?
Now the question is "what nice property of $\gamma$ can ensure its image is a straight line?"

@tbrugere yes I do, $\gamma (0) = 1$ and $\gamma (1) = i$. It should be pretty clear that I don't know how to arrive at the solution from this so I don't know why you are getting me to play this game of cat and mouse.

well you already know the result, you're looking for the reasoning to get to it, so I am walking you through that, sorry if it seemed aggressive

@tbrugere the nice property would be the linearity of t's terms, so some $at+bti+c$.

alright then you got it, affine function, you know the result in two points, so you just have to solve a linear system, I'll show it in answer
(note that $c$ in your above formula should be a complex number)

There seems to be some internal contradiction in your post. If you want a path from $i$ to $1$ then I would expect that your intention is $\gamma(0)=i$ and $\gamma(1)=1$. However, the formula $\gamma(t) = 1-t + it$ does not work for that purpose, because $\gamma(0)=1$ and $\gamma(1)=i$. Perhaps the words "from" and "to" mean something different than I expected...

The line through $w = u + iv$ and $z = x + iy$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is parametrized by
$$
\gamma(t) = (1-t)w + tz.
$$
In this form, it's clear that $\gamma(0) = w$ and $\gamma(1) = z$, so if you only want the segment connecting $w$ to $z$, restrict the parameter to the interval $[0, 1]$.
However, by expanding and rearranging, we can also write this as
$$
\gamma(t) = w + (z - w)t, 
$$
which makes it clear that for positive values of the parameter $t$, the ray begins at $w$ and points in the direction of the vector (complex number) $z - w$, as expected.
Either form is correct, and you can substitute in your particular values for the base points $w = i$ and $z = 1$ (or vice versa; it's not clear).

You are looking for a $\gamma$ that is $\mathbb{R}$-affine, so that
$\gamma(0) = 1$
$\gamma(1) = i$
$\gamma(t) = a t + b$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$
Which gives you a linear system
$$a \times 0 + b = 1$$
$$a \times 1 + b = i$$
from which you should quickly get the result: $b = 1, a= i-1$.
thus the result you already had
$$\gamma(t) = 1 + (i - 1)t$$
